# Find last node in unknown amount of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can find last node like this

```
MATCH p=(a)-->(b)-->(c)
WHERE a.name='Object' AND c:Prime
RETURN c
```

But how i would find last node if i don't know how many relationships -->()-->() between two nodes?

I am trying to find last Node name by the Lable name. Last node doesn't have any outgoing relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will find `c` in an arbitrarily long path where c has not outgoing relationships.

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*]->(c:Prime)
WHERE a.name='Object' 
AND not( c-->() )
RETURN c
```

It is generally advisable to use relationship types (if possible / practical) in your query and put an upward boundary on the number of hops your match can make.  The example below follows only relationships of type `CONNECTION` in one direction to a maximum of 5 relationships.

```
MATCH p=(a)-[:CONNECTION*..5]->(c:Prime)
WHERE a.name='Object' 
AND not( c-->() )
RETURN c
```

Comment: You are the best, Dave)